# write method generic

Tags: python

I have a YML file

```
 e_yml:
 a: https://www.google.com:8201/jde/
```

As I use write and read into YML file methods in most of my test case

But as the above method is restricted to only 3 keys and more of hardcoded, to be more generic I am trying this logic
Here output it is writing only 'value' into YML file

Instead of updating the `key[a]` it is overwriting only the value into YML.

Can someone please help me to update only the key?

Comment: How is this a Python question exactly ???

Comment: No, this is ruby..

Comment: It is completely unclear why you think you need to specify key `e_yml` in  your `write()` example. You can only have one key `a` in your toplevel mapping, so you don't need to provide it as some sort of context.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

Write a value to the hash’s deeply nested key.

#### Solution

```
def deep_write(hash, value, *keys)
  hash.tap do |h|
    keys[0...-1].inject(h) { |h, k| h[k] ||= {} }[keys.last] = value
  end
end
```

#### Check

```
hash = {}
deep_write(hash, '5678234', 'jde_env', 'py')
#⇒ { "jde_env" => { "py" => "5678234" } }
```

#### Usage

```
def write(filename, value, *args)
  data = DataMagic.load(filename)
  File.write(
    File.join(YML_DIR_PATH, filename),
    deep_write(data, value, *args).to_yaml
  )
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. One last question can you please explain the logic [keys.last] = value in deep_write method.

Comment: You want to recursively dig not to the very last level, but to the pre-last (_note the **triple-dot range**_.) `inject` will return the hash on the last level and our goal is to set it’s key to the value. `pre_dig = keys[0...-1].inject(h) { |h, k| h[k] ||= {} }; pre_dig[keys.last] = value` ⇐ I have just written that in one single line.

Comment: got it...Thanks for the explanation..